# Stored procedure => update table with new data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, `Price List` and `Price Code`:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceLists
(
    PriceListID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Reference NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Each `Price List` had lots of price codes:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceCodes
(
    PriceCodeID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    PriceListID INT NOT NULL
    PriceCodeName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Basically what I need is a stored procedure; when a new price list is entered, that stored procedure is going to add same number of price codes to the `PriceCodes` table with new `PriceListID`.

For example:

If a new row is inserted into the `PriceList` table with `PriceListID = 1` and `Reference = 2017`, then the stored procedure should insert these rows into the `PriceCode` table:

```
PriceCodeID    PriceListID   PriceCodeName
------------------------------------------
    1               1        CodeA 
    2               1        CodeB 
    3               1        CodeC
```

And if we have this data in the `PriceList` table :

```
PriceListID    Reference
------------------------
      1          2017 
      1          2018
```

then the `PriceCodse` table should be like this:

```
PriceCodeID    PriceListID   PriceCodeName
------------------------------------------
    1               1        CodeA 
    2               1        CodeB 
    3               1        CodeC
    4               2        CodeA 
    5               2        CodeB 
    6               2        CodeC
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER  Management St v17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily package this up into an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, and even get rid of that ugly cursor - try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_InsertPriceCodes
ON dbo.PriceLists
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.PriceCodes (PriceListID, PriceCodeName)
        SELECT i.PriceListID, VAL.Name
        FROM Inserted i
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('CodeA'), ('CodeB'), ('CodeC')) AS VAL(Name) 
END
```

So now, any time you insert a row into `PriceLists`, the trigger will take care of adding three rows with values `CodeA`, `CodeB`, and `CodeC` for `PriceCodeName` into the `PriceCodes` table. No stored procedure and no RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) trigger necessary.....

Comment: Thank you for your help Mark. But Code A, , B, C are just an example. There are lots of Cods in DB. I need a loop or something similar to add all of it.

Comment: @Adil: put all those codes into a separate table, and then use that table in the CROSS APPLY, instead of the `VALUES(....)` - no **RBAR loops** needed!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and it seems working, just need few adjustments.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @priceCodeName VARCHAR(50), @PriceListID INT, @PriceGroup VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE priceCode_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  PriceCodeName ,PriceListID ,PriceGroup
FROM PriceCodes2
ORDER BY PriceCodeName;

OPEN priceCode_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM priceCode_cursor
INTO @priceCodeName, @PriceListID, @PriceGroup

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PriceCodes2]
           ([PriceCodeName]
           ,[PriceListID]
           ,[PriceGroup])
     VALUES
           (@priceCodeName,@PriceListID,@PriceGroup)

    FETCH NEXT FROM priceCode_cursor
    INTO @priceCodeName, @PriceListID, @PriceGroup

END
CLOSE priceCode_cursor;
DEALLOCATE  priceCode_cursor;
```

Comment: This is **not** an answer - if you want to add something, you should **EDIT** your existing question and add the additional information there - not post what is not an answer here ......